# Difference between JavaScript's function calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm having a problem understanding the differences between the function calls below. Specifically in React or any other JavaScript frameworks.

Assuming that `func()` is

```
const func = () => {
  console.log("func() called");
  return 1;
}
```

how will these three invocations be different?

```
<Button onClick={()=>func()} >test</Button>
```

```
<Button onClick={func()} >test</Button>
```

```
<Button onClick={func} >test</Button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

This creates a new lambda function that calls func during the onClick event:

```
<Button onClick={()=>func()} >test</Button>
```

This calls func immediately and assigns the result to onClick. Since func returns a non-function this is an error:

```
<Button onClick={func()} >test</Button>
```

Becomes:

```
<Button onClick={1} >test</Button>
```

And this assigns func to the onClick handler. It's functionally identical to the first example.

```
<Button onClick={func} >test</Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a huge difference in the way it is evaluated and executed.

```
<Button onClick={()=>func()} >test</Button>
```

This will will wrap original function `func` in another function and the wrapper function will be bound to the event and will be called.

```
<Button onClick={func()} >test</Button>
```

This will invoke function immediately and will bind result of the function call to onClick event.

```
<Button onClick={func} >test</Button>
```

This however, will bind `func` event to onClick event and will be called when ever even is invoked.

Answer (score -1):

I would like contribute sharing the follow link where you can find extra explanation: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onclick-event-handling-with-examples

[image]

[image]